# Getting value from a database using textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
 string que = "SELECT Name FROM StudentInfo where StudentNo=textBox1.Text ";
```

Every time I run this it always says that

> "The multi-part identifier "textBox1.Text" could not be bound".

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you actually doing it like `"SELECT Name FROM StudentInfo where StudentNo=textBox1.Text ";` and not `"SELECT Name FROM StudentInfo where StudentNo='" + textBox1.Text+  "';`?

Comment: @AlexJolig: No, the OP in't doing that at the moment - that would give a different error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the query include the value from the textbox. SQL Server doesn't know anything about your textbox - you've just provided the text `textBox1.Text` as if it refers to something that SQL Server knows about. However, you shouldn't include the value from your textbox *in* the SQL itself...

Instead, you should parameterize your SQL, and set the parameter from your textbox as a value to be sent *alongside* the SQL when you execute the query:

```
// Assuming an open connection...
int studentNo = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
string sql = "SELECT Name FROM StudentInfo where StudentNo=@student_no";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(conn, sql))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@student_no", SqlDbType.Int).Value = studentNo;
    // Execute the command as normal
}
```

This assumes that the type of `StudentNo` in your database is `Int`, of course - adjust accordingly (along with what you do with `textBox1.Text` - I'm currently parsing it as an `int`).

You should always parameterize your SQL rather than trying include the value within the SQL itself, for three important reasons:

- It protects against [SQL Injection Attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- It avoids unnecessary conversions, and gives you more control over the conversions you *do* need
- It typically makes it easier to read the SQL (as there isn't string concatenation code etc involved) so you can find issues with that more simply

Comment: I'm voting this up just because it's Jon Skeet!

Comment: @AlexJolig: Never do that. Only vote up an answer if you think it's useful. If you think one of my answers is unhelpful, you should absolutely down-vote it. Everyone makes mistakes sometimes :)

Comment: I know. I was kidding. And I'm sure you always describe the solution in the best way. Just like this one.

Answer (score 2):

You should be parameterizing your query:

```
string que = "SELECT Name FROM StudentInfo WHERE StudentNo = @StudentNo"

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@StudentNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox1.Text;

        //If StudentNo is Int
        //command.Parameters.Add("@StudentNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int) textBox1.Text;

        connection.Open();

        string veri = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
        return veri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
string strQuery = "SELECT Name FROM StudentInfo where StudentNo= @studentno";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentno", textBox1.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: You might want to read http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score -1):

I really dont understand your question but the query should be

```
string que = "SELECT Name FROM StudentInfo where StudentNo= '" + textBox1.Text + "';";
```

If the StudentNo is Varchar in the DB. or else

```
string que = "SELECT Name FROM StudentInfo where StudentNo=" + textBox1.Text + ";";
```

Where as you should go for parameterized query like this

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT Name FROM StudentInfo where StudentNo=@No", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("No", textBox1.Text));
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
    }
```

Comment: If you know about parameterized SQL, why would you initially suggest something insecure, saying "the query should be" as if it's fine?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes I agree bcoz I treat it as one of the way of doing things. It might be insecure but OP better knows if he really wanted to implement or not. Since it is a very basic query building error that seems the OP is starting up and not working for some project which could be used by many users.

Comment: Yes, the OP is quite possibly early into their journey into software engineering - so why are you encouraging them to get into bad habits? However inexperienced the OP is, suggesting an approach which invites SQL Injection Attacks is simply a bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think we should give the answer to the OP which fits his requirements and accomplish his job with a suggestion of better way of doing things. My way is to give suggestion with nearest code or suggestion which OP has tried with better solution/approach to do the same thing. Its Okay! I wont edit my answer.

Comment: Then I won't change my vote :) I believe your approach is actively harmful to new developers, who should be told to use parameterized SQL - with reasons - as early as possible, before they get into bad habits. Likewise if the OP says something like "I'm storing passwords in plaintext in the database" you should inform them of how dangerous that is, and more appropriate approaches to authentication. We have a responsibility to educate, IMO.